# Java- Using invokeAll to get future results in order but only for some threads

Tags: java, threadpool, future, executors

I...really don't know how to word the title better. But basically, what I have is a thread pool with all these threads busily working. I want them to report their results in the order that they were assigned, but at the same time, I want to work in batches. To illustrate, and example would be

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

class MyCallable implements Callable<byte[]> {
    private final int threadnumber;

    MyCallable(int threadnumber){
        this.threadnumber = threadnumber;
    }

    public byte[] call() {
        //does something
    }
}
List<Callable<byte[]>> callables = new ArrayList<Callable<byte[]>>();

for(int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    callables.add(new MyCallable(i));
}
try {
    List<Future<byte[]>> results = exec.invokeAll(callables);
    for(Future<byte[]> result: results) {
            System.out.write(result.get(), 0, result.get().length);
    }
```

Basically, the pool thread has 8 threads and I end up having 20 tasks (these are just examples). The way this works now, if I understand correctly, is that it waits until ALL 20 tasks are done before outputting them in order (from 1 to 20). What this program is supposed to do is output a continuous stream of bytes (which were processed by threads, and since I need to keep the order intact, I used the future interface). While I don't mind waiting until all 20 tasks are done, is there anyway so that the threads simply output in order as they go.

If there's no way or I'm just completely misunderstanding how invokeAll works, clarification there is welcome too. Thanks a bunch in advance! Executors are a bit confusing since I only just learned about them.

Random addendum, am I even allowed to return a byte array from a callable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`invokeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) waits until all results are computed before it returns.

Use a loop and [`submit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) them one by one instead, this method returns a Future with the pending result immediately:

```
...
for(int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    results.add(exec.submit(new MyCallable(i))); 
}
try {
    for(Future<Integer> result: results) {
            System.out.write(result.get(), 0, result.get().length);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: But if the threads ran out of order, wouldn't that make my array out of order too? For example, I want the output to be 1,2,3... but if thread 3 finished first, wouldn't it return first also? Or is that handled somewhere automatically? I'm still learning about callable and future interfaces

Comment: @TT: No, since this code traverses the list with futures in order, the results will be output in the same order they were added to the list. The `get()` method blocks until that particular `Future` has a result.

Comment: Thank you so much! So basically, the order I submit it in is the order it looks for futures in. Man, this is stuff is really useful. I was running around with a bunch of runnables that were asynchronous and not being able to get the results in order. So I actually don't need the callables array here since I'm adding to results one by one and not waiting for all results.

Comment: @TT: Yes, the ExecutorService is really powerful. :) Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Using invokeAll also you can achieve.

```
 List<Future<byte[]>> results = exec.invokeAll(callables);
```

It will return the future object list.

ThreadPoll will execute the tasks in random order . Task execution order cannnot be controlled.

**Future Object**

1. Its a reference of task which is submitted in ThreadPool.
2. It has a method **get()**. Its a blocking call method. If you invoke the get() method ,call will be wait until tasks get completed.

**How to ensure Tasks submission order**

Results order is same in callables order. Even thread pool will execute in different order we can retrieve in same order.

For Ex .

Three Tasks 1,2,3

1 & 3 --> Completed.

2 ------> Taking long time to execute.

After calling invokeAll method It will return List of Future in same order.

Task 1 : Future#get method return result since its already completed

Task 2 : Future#get method waits till task will complete.

Iteration waits till second task will complete even though third task completed. It wont get result from third thread.